# C# -Decrypt password throws error-The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character

Tags: c#, string, encryption, cryptography

I am using following method to decrypt my password:

```
var encryptedstring = "__utmc=1; __utma=1.1379697434.1428532783.1428532783.1428532783.1; __utmb=1.4.10.1428532783; __utmz=1.1428532783.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmt=1; AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAAnu1D5k/osU6aUvqIYSeF0gAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAABxRKV16Z/rmwCDJ14qOw09LPpYST26ttDoAtzEkEaE5AAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAACo9ZWuW9nj0rQtgM6nefu6EE6bxNqklVVpzsHqf1HKRCAAAADzMPYSaE1KRBeAemPjsHdM2dAABzAaAF9EsOaVUs+OoEAAAAARxP9cg3UwTLH7SsQfTJixVo1FkIOErLSyA/mzzAA8KxT1wp5ANsVpE6BYA2BLzBAvKqLZ2FhxamPA96xXiGec";

var decryptstring = Decrypt(encryptedstring);

public string Decrypt(string cipher)
    {
        if (cipher == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("cipher");

        //parse base64 string
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(cipher);

        //decrypt data
        byte[] decrypted = ProtectedData.Unprotect(data, null, Scope);
        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decrypted);
    }
```

It throws the following exception at `Convert.FromBase64String`

```
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
```

**EDIT:**

Added the Encrypt code:

```
  public static string EncryptProtected(string plainText)
    {
        if (plainText == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        var data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);
        byte[] encrypted = ProtectedData.Protect(data, null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
    }
```

Comment: That first line is not valid C# and it won't compile. Not to mention you aren't using any of those variables in your `Decrypt` function. Or is that entire first line meant to be the string `cipher`?

Comment: error message says it all. That string isnt base64   A-Z,a-z,0-9 + and /

Comment: yes @philsoady, you are right. But do you know if there is any conversion function i can use to convert the above string to byte[]

Comment: That string doesn't appear to be an encrypted password; it doesn't make any sense, all those `utm`s. Besides, passwords are usually hashed, which is one-way; you can't recover the original data from a hash. Where did that string come from?

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline- added the encrypted code,the string is coming from the encrypted function

Comment: At a guess you're storing this encrypted data in a cookie, and then trying to extract it from the cookie and decrypt. Unfortunately, your `encryptedstring` appears to be the concatenation of *all* the cookies sent to your page, not just the one you set containing the password (the "utm..." ones are all Google Analytics cookies). The piece you want is the part after the last semicolon, i.e. "AQAAA...XiGec" which *is* Base64 encoded and should decode correctly. You will therefore need to extract this section out before performing the Base64 decode.

Comment: Thanks @Iridium - for finding the issue . However can i get some pointers how can i remove the google analytics cookies? Currently i am passing the document.cookie to the server directly.I don't want to disable the google analtyics for the enitre website, but only remove them for the password alone.Many Thanks In Advance!